# Html: Trouble appending to nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append to the nested list under ARTCC. Here is an excerpt from the body of the document:

```
<div id="GUI" class="sidenav">
<section id='list' class="ladder tree">
<ul>
<li><a id="ARTCC" href="."><i class="fa fa-cube"></i> <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ARTCC</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a id ="ZAB" href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZAB</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZAU</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZBW</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
```

Here is the funciton that appends items to the list:

```
for(var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {
    var entityId = added[i].name.toLowerCase();
    if(entityId.includes("z")){
        $("#ARTCC ul").append("<li><a id=" + added[i].id + " class=ARTCC href='#'><i class='fa fa-check-square'</i>" + added[i].name + "</a></li>");
    }
}
```

When I use $("#ARTCC ul").append nothing is added to the list.

However,  $("#list ul ul").append does place the items in the correct location but also appends the items to the other list items and it causes a function that relies on $("a.ARTCC").dblclick() to not execute on a double click.

From what I have read "#ARTCC ul" seems to be the correct way to get the result I am looking for but it is currently not working. Am I missing something here?

The end result would add this last element to the list:

```
<li><a id="ARTCC" href="."><i class="fa fa-cube"></i> <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ARTCC</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a id ="ZAB" href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZAB</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZAU</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZBW</a></li>
         //new item
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> NEW ITEM</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: What is "added.length" ? How did you declare it?

Comment: added is an array of entities that gets created when an 'onChanged' function gets called. It works properly and adds the appropriate items when I append to "#list ul ul".

Answer (score 0):

ARTCC doesn't have any ul below it in the document tree. The query selector you have listed is first trying to find an element with the id of "ARTCC", then selecting all ul elements that are within it. It sounds like you're looking to add to this ul:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id ="ZAB" class="ARTCC" href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZAB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZAU</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> ZBW</a></li>
</ul>
```

To do that, change `<ul>` to `<ul id="someId">`, then in jQuery you can do `$('#someId').append(someElement);`

Unless you're trying to append to the *class* `ARTCC` in which you'd do `$('.ARTCC')` but it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I apologize, I thought I had taken class="ARTCC" out of the code before I posted. That was something else I was attempting. If you look above that ul you will see the list item with id="ARTCC" that I am talking about. I want to append to  this nested list that you copied in your comment. To add some context this is all part of a collapsible list that contains other collapsible lists.

Comment: Please edit your question with the end result of how you'd like it to look

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("#ARTCC ul")` to `$("#ARTCC+ul")`. This is `prev` + `next` selector.